# Kubernetes Podspec for Privileged Container and volume mounts of /mnt and /dev of container

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I am able to run following plain docker command and volumes are created and mapped.This is privileged container.

docker run -d --network host --name test_container --volume test_volume:/mnt --privileged -v /dev:/dev $IMAGE_NAME

This container should be deployed as POD in kubernetes.

I tried creating podspec for this and its failing with below error :

Message:      OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: "/mnt/somescript.sh": stat /mnt/somescript.sh: no such file or directory"

Below is the podspec snapshot:

```
spec:
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
  containers:
    image: test_container:latest
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: test-container
    resources: {}
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/mnt"
      name: testvolume
    - mountPath: "/dev"
      name: devdata
  hostNetwork: true
  hostname: test
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: acr-pull
  nodeName: xxxxxx
  restartPolicy: Always
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /mnt
      type: Directory
    name: testvolume
  - hostPath:
      path: /dev
      type: Directory
    name:  devdata
```

Also volumes not getting created for /mnt and /dev dir of containers.

Answer (score 1):

If your directory not exist you can give it try with `DirectoryOrCreate`

```
volumes:
- hostPath:
    path: /mnt
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
  name: testvolume
```

if it's not present it will create the path.

if your file in not getting mounted you can also give it try with **subpath**

```
somescript.sh
```

Comment: DirectoryOrCreate didnt help, Also there are so many files under /mnt and /dev of container. how can we add for all files as subpath. is it possible to mount sys paths /mnt and /dev of container in volumes

Comment: before doing i would recommand verifying once are you sure at /mnt your files getting overwritten by mount path ?

Comment: no its not getting overwritten, i want volumes to be created and then the path /mnt of container to be mounted to that volume. I even tried with PVC as below:    containers:
    image: test_container:latest
    name: test-container
    resources: {}
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/mnt"
      name: test-volume
      subPath: v1/testdata   
    - mountPath: "/dev"
      name: test-volume
      subPath: v1/dev   
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: test-pvc

Comment: When I use docker run -d --network host --name test_container --volume test_volume:/mnt --privileged -v /dev:/dev $IMAGE_NAME its working good, its creating volume ==== test_volume and under this volume i can see the container dir /mnt content also, but through podspec its not working